# What does mean => in "rsync --dry-run" output?

Tags: linux, rsync

I am using rsync -n for dry run to get the file list for the download.
I wondered what does mean in the dry run out:

```
/somedir/somefile => someotherdir/somerotherfile
```

What is the "=>" symbol for ?

**EDIT**

I found it!!! It is a hard linked file. for more information: man rsyncd.conf

Comment: do leave your findings as an answer

Comment: Always RTM 1st! ;)

Answer (score -1):

its an arrow :) as in this is going to move from here ---> to there

Comment: No, it is a hard linked file :). for more information: man rsyncd.conf

Comment: ill look this up when i get back to a nix machine, but im pretty sure on my machine i get that for every single file. oddness.

Comment: i looked this up. When i use rsync its part of a backup shell script, but the script actually ditches the rsync output to /dev/null and part of its own logged output is like [dir from] ===> [dir to]. doh ! ;p I'd better change that as it'll confuse in the future i expect.